# onClick event listener not working in vis-network implementation on salesforce aura component

Tags: javascript, dom-events, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I have implemented vis-network to plot a network on Salesforce aura component.But when clicking on any node of the network it's not working.

```
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
console.log(network);
network.fit();
    
// Add a click event listener to the network to handle node clicks
network.on("click", function (params) {
console.log('clicked');
```

this is not working , anyone who have faced a similar issue and got a solution ?